# enviar valor a un Qwidget desde una clase diferente Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

¿Como puedo cambiar el valor de un Qwidget desde otra clase.

Ejemplo:

```
class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('task.ui',self)

        self.label_1.setText('linea1')

class Segunda(QDialog):
    def __int__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('second',self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(lambda:Primera().label_1.setText('linea1_desde_second_class'))
```

Cambiar el valor de la label en la clase Primera desde un boton en la clase Segunda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las clases son abstracciones, es decir, describen el comportamiento común genérico de un conjunto de elementos, pero no son elementos dinámicos dentro de la aplicación. Los objetos que son creados usando esas clases sí intervienen en la lógica del programa.

Un programa desde el punto de vista de OOP no son un conjunto de archivos, clases o funciones, sino que es la interacción entre los objetos. Asi que tu pregunta tal como esta no se puede resolver.

**Explicación:**

cada vez que llamas a Primera() estas creando un nuevo widget(objeto) de tipo Primera, y entonces tu le estas pasando el nuevo texto a ese widget que se creara, y como esta dentro de una función, esta se destruira apenas termine de ejecutarse la función ya que es una variable local.

La solución correcta asumiendo que has creado en algun lugar el objeto de la clase Primera() y en ese mismo lugar se puede acceder al objeto creado por la clase Segunda():

```
# en alguna parte de tu codigo
self.objeto_primero = Primero()
self.objeto_segundo = Segundo()
self.objeto_segundo.boton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.objeto_primero.label_1.setText('linea1_desde_second_class'))
```

---

Como recomendación debe revisar las bases de OOP, PyQt y Qt se basan en ello y si usted no tiene ese conocimiento afianzado tendra mucho más problemas.